# SSL app on page works fine (https). How to make this available for non-ssl visitors?

Tags: facebook, apache, ssl

No problems with making our webserver secure. App on Facebook runs fine IF 'secure browsing' opted in (user-setting). How can we make our App visible for visitors who has not opted in on 'secure browsing'?

Do we have to make a copy of the site on a insecure (http) server? Or is there another solution? (force to non-ssl via htaccess)

Comment: What kind of web server? Apache, IIS, etc ...

Comment: I know that in IIS you can allow http and https traffic on the same site. I'm pretty sure you can do the same with Apache, but someone else will have to answer that.

Answer (score 0):

There should be no issue with setting both app urls, in your Facebook app settings, to use the https url.